# Set input text value and set data value in checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So, I am using a snippet to change the value of input texts and checkboxes (tick them) based on a dictionary. So, we are talking about very common questions. If the question (span above the input text) is Age, it should return the number. If the question is Gender, it should tick the relevant box underneath and make sure it is true before submitting the form (google form for this example). I noticed that for every questions box `document.querySelector("#mG61Hd > div.RH5hzf.RLS9Fe > div > div.o3Dpx > div:nth-child(2) > div > div")` has an id. So, the id equals the child plus X where X = 3 and then every time it increases to X+3:

- 5 = 2 + 3
- 9 = 3 + 6
- 13 = 4 + 9
- 17 = 5 + 12 and so on

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// Define the dictionary with keys and values you want to return
const myself = {
  "Full Name": "My Name",
  "Phone": "07666444500",
  "Age": "26",
  "Email": "mymail@gmail.com",
  "Gender": "Female",
  "Ethnicity":"White British"
};

  for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { 
    let hId = "#i" + ((i - 1) * 4 + 1);
    let hElement = document.querySelector(`${hId} > span.M7eMe`);
    let h = hElement ? hElement.textContent.trim() : null; 

    let inputSelector = `#mG61Hd > div.RH5hzf.RLS9Fe > div > div.o3Dpx > div:nth-child(${i}) > div > div > div.AgroKb > div > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input`;
    let inputElement = document.querySelector(inputSelector);

    if (myself[h]) {
      if (inputElement && inputElement.type === "radio") {
        let radioGroup = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name='${inputElement.name}']`);
        for (let j = 0; j < radioGroup.length; j++) {
          if (radioGroup[j].value.toLowerCase() === myself[h].toLowerCase()) {
            radioGroup[j].checked = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else if (inputElement) {
        inputElement.value = myself[h];
      } else {
        let radioDiv = document.querySelector(`div[role='radio'][data-value='${myself[h]}']`);
        if (radioDiv) {
          radioDiv.click();
        }
      }

      if (inputElement) {
        inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSf4dPFtGUXJVuMnMmZYgFsbFaDnZ8ED4tiiYV4ENObHfRYyPQ/formResponse" target="_self" method="POST" id="mG61Hd" jsmodel="TOfxwf Q91hve CEkLOc" data-shuffle-seed="-5791707696025457682" data-clean-viewform-url="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf4dPFtGUXJVuMnMmZYgFsbFaDnZ8ED4tiiYV4ENObHfRYyPQ/viewform?usp=sf_link" data-response="%.@.]" data-dlp-data="%.@.null,false]" data-first-entry="0" data-last-entry="18" data-is-first-page="true">

  <div class="RH5hzf RLS9Fe">
    <div class="lrKTG">
      <div class="o3Dpx" role="list">
        <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
          <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1145350593,&quot;Full Name&quot;,null,0,[[988383412,null,true,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]]],null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,&quot;Full Name&quot;]],&quot;i1&quot;,&quot;i2&quot;,&quot;i3&quot;,false]">
            <div jscontroller="sWGJ4b" jsaction="EEvAHc:yfX9oc;" jsname="WsjYwc" class="geS5n">
              <div class="z12JJ">
                <div class="M4DNQ">
                  <div id="i1" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i4">
                    <span class="M7eMe">Full Name</span>
                    <span class="vnumgf" id="i4" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i2"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div jscontroller="oCiKKc" jsaction="rcuQ6b:vZc4S;O22p3e:zjh6rb;b2trFe:eVidQc;sPvj8e:d3sQLd;AHmuwe:h06R8;" class="AgroKb">
                <div class="rFrNMe k3kHxc RdH0ib yqQS1 zKHdkd" jscontroller="pxq3x" jsaction="clickonly:KjsqPd; focus:Jt1EX; blur:fpfTEe; input:Lg5SV" jsshadow="" jsname="YPqjbf">
                  <div class="aCsJod oJeWuf">
                    <div class="aXBtI Wic03c">
                      <div class="Xb9hP">
                        <input type="text" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" aria-disabled="false" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="">
                      </div>
                      <div class="i9lrp mIZh1c"></div>
                      <div jsname="XmnwAc" class="OabDMe cXrdqd"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="LXRPh">
                    <div jsname="ty6ygf" class="ovnfwe Is7Fhb"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i3" role="alert"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
          <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[611627761,&quot;Phone&quot;,null,0,[[89548986,null,true,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]]],null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,&quot;Phone&quot;]],&quot;i5&quot;,&quot;i6&quot;,&quot;i7&quot;,false]">
            <div jscontroller="sWGJ4b" jsaction="EEvAHc:yfX9oc;" jsname="WsjYwc" class="geS5n">
              <div class="z12JJ">
                <div class="M4DNQ">
                  <div id="i5" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i8">
                    <span class="M7eMe">Phone</span>
                    <span class="vnumgf" id="i8" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i6"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div jscontroller="oCiKKc" jsaction="rcuQ6b:vZc4S;O22p3e:zjh6rb;b2trFe:eVidQc;sPvj8e:d3sQLd;AHmuwe:h06R8;" class="AgroKb">
                <div class="rFrNMe k3kHxc RdH0ib yqQS1 zKHdkd" jscontroller="pxq3x" jsaction="clickonly:KjsqPd; focus:Jt1EX; blur:fpfTEe; input:Lg5SV" jsshadow="" jsname="YPqjbf">
                  <div class="aCsJod oJeWuf">
                    <div class="aXBtI Wic03c">
                      <div class="Xb9hP">
                        <input type="text" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i5" aria-describedby="i6 i7" aria-disabled="false" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
          <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1244337291,&quot;Age&quot;,null,0,[[1920163779,null,true,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]]],null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,&quot;Age&quot;]],&quot;i9&quot;,&quot;i10&quot;,&quot;i11&quot;,false]">
            <div jscontroller="sWGJ4b" jsaction="EEvAHc:yfX9oc;" jsname="WsjYwc" class="geS5n"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

It seems to be working in the snippet but it does not overall. I have saved everything in a snippet to prove it:

https://jsfiddle.net/radomer/p5xc6rdz/

where you can see that some values change and some others do not. I can definitely not see the radio boxes being ticked. I have been trying different version but I fail. Where is the main issue of this? Is it based on my calculation of ids? Is it also because I have to change the tabindex and aria-checked to true for the checkbox questions?

PS: For the purpose of cutting down HTML code, I removed some questions. The same applies for the jsfiddle and the snippet.

Comment: It's hard to debug because the JsFiddle won't work properly, I assume due to missing javascript to handle the radio buttons. But I feel like you're overcomplicating the issue by relying on the id's. You can get all list items with `document.querySelectorAll('div[role=listitem]')`, then you can get the header with `listItem.querySelector('div[role=heading] > span:first-child')`. I couldn't get further because the JsFiddle crashes my tab with how large it is.

Comment: @Steffen I made the HTML simpler in the jsfiddle. The listItem did not work in Chrome console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script, I made a Google Forms and tested it myself on small-text inputs, radio buttons and checkboxes. It doesn't use any dynamic class names for selection, so it should work on any form.

```
const values = {
    'Gender': 'Female',
    'Name': 'My name',
    'City': 'Copenhagen',
    'Tick whatever you want': 'Option 2',
    'E-mail': 'test@gmail.com'
};

document.querySelectorAll('div[role=listitem]').forEach(listItem => {
    const headingElement = listItem.querySelector('div[role=heading] > span:first-child');
    if(!headingElement) return;

    const heading = headingElement.innerText.trim();

    const optionsContainer = listItem.querySelector('div[jscontroller]:nth-child(2)');
    const textInput = optionsContainer.querySelector('input[type=text]:not([aria-label])');
    if(textInput) {
        textInput.value = values[heading];
        textInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
    }
    else {
        console.log(listItem);
        const optionLabels = listItem.querySelectorAll('label[for]');
        console.log(optionLabels);
        optionLabels.forEach(optionLabel => {
            const value = optionLabel.querySelector('div > div:nth-child(2) span').innerText.trim();
            if(value == values[heading]) {
                const clickableElement = listItem.querySelector(`#${optionLabel.getAttribute('for')}`);
                clickableElement.click();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image: Image of form result after running script]

Comment: Input texts work perfectly. However, the radio buttons do not. Most of them have an option of "Other" where you add your own text. Is it possible to make it select the option with the data value equals to "Male" etc? I can create a snippet with how one checkbox question looks like

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/radomer/t6pg4Ldr/

Comment: @Datacrawler Updated the selector to use `input[type=text]:not([aria-label])` instead of just `input[type=text]`

Comment: I made it work. It ignored one input because it says it was a textarea instead of a text type.